# Android: How do I get a ColorStateList from resources?

Tags: android

I am making a navigation drawer where the icon is coloured based on the colour of the text.

This is my `selector` declared in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

This is my `ViewHolder`

```java
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,iconResourceId);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(),mContext.gerResouces.getColorStateList());
mItemIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

As you can see the problem i am having is on this line, what do i pass in `getColorStateList`? The doucmentation is not helping me.

```
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(),mContext.gerResouces.getColorStateList());
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass the id of the color state list resource, e.g. `R.color.my_color_state_list`. Color state lists belong in `res/color`, not `res/drawable`.

```
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(),
    mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_color_state_list));
```

Comment: This is now deprecated, use `ContextCompat.getColorStateList()`. See @peuhse's answer.

Answer (score 28):

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.your_color_selector);
snackBar.setActionTextColor(colorStateList);
```